# From many columns to one of the columns inside single row

Tags: sql

I want to get the data from multiple columns into one of the columns that return to the same row at the end of the query. (line by line in a single column while other columns repeat)

```
    SELECT A.ID, A.ITEM, A.NUMBER, B.DETAIL1, B.DETAIL2
    FROM MAIN_TABLE A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DETAIL_TABLE B ON (A.ID=B.AID)
```

The query result is as follows:

```
    ID | ITEM | NUMBER | DETAIL1    DETAIL2
    --  ------  ------  ---------   --------
    S1  DESK1       10  Small       Medium
    S2  DESK2       25  Large       X-Large
```

It should be like this:

```
    ID | ITEM | NUMBER | DETAILS
    --  ------  ------  ---------
    S1  DESK1       10  Small
    S1  DESK1       10  Medium
    S2  DESK2       25  Large
    S2  DESK2       25  X-Large
```

I used cursor but it didn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: As the *sql tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS. Also the source sample data is always useful.

Comment: This known as 'unpivot' oper. Consult your DBMS manuals.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a UNION to "unpivot" the detail table:

```
SELECT a.id, a.item, a.number, b.detail
FROM main_table a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, detail1 as detail
    FROM detail_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, detail2 as detail
    FROM detail_table
  ) b on a.id=b.aid
```

Another option is to use a lateral cross join to do the unpivot:

```
SELECT a.id, a.item, a.number, b.detail
FROM main_table a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT dt.id, u.detail
    FROM detail_table dt
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES (dt.detail1), (dt.detail2) ) as u(detail)
   ) b on a.id=b.aid
```

Both queries are 100% standard ANSI SQL. However not all DBMS actually do support lateral joins or even the `values` clause like that.